# Linux file server WAN optmization

Tags: linux, networking, router, vpn, bgp

How can I optimize my file server traffic between 1 asynchronous and  1 synchronous connection (via VPN)? Something like Branch Cache or RiverBed WAN Optimization, but between two sites with Linux servers?

I'm just curious. Traffic would be primarily file transfer traffic.

Setup would be, site to site VPN from a Office with a dedicated internet(fiber) and a branch office with a DSL asynchronous connection. Linux Ubuntu Severs on each site.

Comment: can you transfer my question then?

Comment: Only mods can do that. Flag your question "in need of moderator intervention" and ask a mod to move it.

Comment: Also I'm not looking for just software. I am looking for how to resolve this question. If thats a better form to do so, then thats fine.

Comment: Then you need to reword your question. Maybe replace "Are there Linux utility programs that will optimize your traffic" with "How do I optimize my traffic..."

Comment: Close vote retracted ;)

Comment: Would splitting large files into smaller ones(7zip does this) but automatically , sending them to dest then put them back together be an option?